# How to tell if series elements contain question mark in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a series of text posts (df['posttext']). Each of the rows in this series are strings. I want to know which ones contain a question mark.

When I try

```
df['posttext'].str.contains("?")
```

I get this:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0.
```

Answer (score 8):

This `contains` method expects a regular expression. [You can turn that off](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/strings.py#L1564) by supplying a keyword argument called `regex`:

```
df['posttext'].str.contains("?", regex=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the question mark to force it to look for the literal character

```
df['posttext'].str.contains("\?")
```

Comment: This only coincidentally works, you should either double-escape the question mark (`"\\?"`), or use raw strings (`r"\?"`).

Comment: The `regex=False` is definitely the best answer anyway, as it's explicit and self documenting. In this use-case, the single escape worked, so I presented it as is. Thanks for clarifying, definitely informative!